How to sum all the elements in a group in specific row with the package `listofitems`?
The MWE is following:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems,pgffor}
\setsepchar{;/,}\ignoreemptyitems

\readlist*\foo{
    foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5;
    3,1,4,1,5
}

\begin{document}

Elements in the second line of the group are: \foo[2], and there are \listlen\foo[2] elements in the second line of the group.

I can figure out the summation of them is 14 with my brain. But! I need a command to output `14' automatically.

\end{document}

What's more, I would like to keep the package listofitems, someone can just use expl3 to sum the second line of the group, not to use expl3 to read and print the elements in the group instead listofitems.

I added a listofitems based code for the particular problem

You can just \numexpr the individual list elements together.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems,pgffor}
\setsepchar{;/,}\ignoreemptyitems

\readlist*\foo{
    foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5;
    3,1,4,1,5
}

\begin{document}

Elements in the second line of the group are: 3,1,4,1,5; and the summation of them is 14.

I need a command to output `14'.

I can output the elements in the second line one by one:

\foreachitem\i\in\foo[2]{\i,}

\def\mysum{0}
\foreachitem\z\in\foo[2]{%
\xdef\mysum{\the\numexpr\mysum+\z\relax}%
}
Sum is \mysum.

\end{document}



I'd set up a new data type, which I implement through property lists.
When an array is defined, by giving it a name, the property list is populated with the rows and also with the single items, for faster access.
A row is stored as a comma separated list and I define a \getrow command that delivers the row, with a separator that can be customized.
If the separator is +, then the list can be fed to \inteval, so
\inteval{\getrow{foo}[+]{2}}

is just what you want.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newarray}{mm}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = items (; separates rows)
  \meiu_array_define:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__meiu_array_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__meiu_array_row_seq
\int_new:N \l__meiu_array_ncols_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \meiu_array_define:nn
 {
  % define a property list
  \prop_new:c { g_meiu_array_#1_prop }
  % populate it; first get the rows
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__meiu_array_rows_seq { ; } {#2}
  % now process each row; items in the property list
  % are indexed by 'row number@column number'
  \int_zero:N \l__meiu_array_ncols_int % to store the number of cols
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__meiu_array_rows_seq
   {% ##1 is the index, ##2 is the row
    % rows are stored as clists
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_meiu_array_#1_prop } { ##1 } { ##2 }
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__meiu_array_row_seq {##2}
    % update the number of columns
    \int_set:Nn \l__meiu_array_ncols_int
     {
      \int_max:nn { \l__meiu_array_ncols_int } { \seq_count:N \l__meiu_array_row_seq }
     }
    % add the items
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__meiu_array_row_seq
     {
      \prop_gput:cnn { g_meiu_array_#1_prop } { ##1@####1 } {####2}
     }
   }
  % we store also the number of rows
  \prop_gput:cne { g_meiu_array_#1_prop } { rows } { \seq_count:N \l__meiu_array_rows_seq }
  \prop_gput:cne { g_meiu_array_#1_prop } { cols } { \int_eval:n { \l__meiu_array_ncols_int } }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getitem}{mmm}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = row index, #3 = column index
  \prop_item:ce { g_meiu_array_#1_prop } { #2 \tl_if_blank:nF {#3} {@#3} }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getrow}{O{,~}mm}
 {% #1 = output separator, #2 = array name, #3 = row index
  \clist_use:en { \prop_item:cn { g_meiu_array_#2_prop } {#3} } {#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_use:nn {e}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getrowlen}{mm}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = row index
  \clist_count:e { \prop_item:cn { g_meiu_array_#1_prop } {#2} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newarray{foo}{
  foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5;
  3,1,4,1,5
}

\begin{document}

Elements in the second line of the group are: \getrow{foo}{2}, 
and there are \getrowlen{foo}{2} elements in the second line of the group.

The sum of items in the second row is \inteval{\getrow[+]{foo}{2}}

There are \getitem{foo}{rows}{} rows in the array.

There are \getitem{foo}{cols}{} columns in the array.

The item in row 1 column 3 is \getitem{foo}{1}{3}.

\end{document}


With listofitems:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems,pgffor}
\setsepchar{;/,}\ignoreemptyitems

\readlist*\foo{
    foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5;
    3,1,4,1,5
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\rowsum}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name, #2 = row
  \int_eval:n { \clist_use:en { #1[#2] } { + } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_use:nn {e}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Elements in the second line of the group are: \foo[2], and there
are \listlen\foo[2] elements in the second line of the group.

I can figure out the summation of them is 14 with my brain.
But! I need a command to output `14' automatically.

Here it is: \rowsum{\foo}{2}

\end{document}


Alternatively, use a “normalizer” function:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getrow}{O{,~}mm}
 {% #1 = separator, #2 = list name, #3 = row
  \clist_use:en { #2[#3] } { #1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_use:nn {e}
\ExplSyntaxOff

and your sum is computed by \inteval{\getrow[+]{\foo}{2}}.

just curiosity: did you look at the code of listofitems before answering?

@cfr No, I didn’t.

I thought that might be why you didn't use it ;).

Here's a straight forward way using expl3, as you asked for:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems}%,pgffor}
\setsepchar{;/,}\ignoreemptyitems

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \readlist*\foo{
        foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5;
        3,1,4,1,5
    }
    
    \newcommand\foosum[0]{
        % ~~~ initialization ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \int_new:N  \l_int_mine_cnt
        \int_set:Nn \l_int_mine_cnt { \listlen\foo[2] }
        
        \int_new:N  \l_int_mine_sum
        \int_set:Nn \l_int_mine_sum { 0 }
        
        % ~~~ loop, i.e. sum it up ~~~~~~~~~
        \int_while_do:nn { \l_int_mine_cnt > 0 } {
            % ~~~ sum up ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \int_set:Nn \l_int_mine_sum {
                \l_int_mine_sum + \foo[2,\l_int_mine_cnt]}
            % ~~~ end-condition ~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \int_set:Nn \l_int_mine_cnt { \l_int_mine_cnt - 1 }
        }
        
        % ~~~ "return" sum, i.e. put it into the output stream ~~~
        \int_use:N \l_int_mine_sum
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff



% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

Elements in the second line of the group are: \foo[2], and there are \listlen\foo[2] elements in the second line of the group.

I can figure out the summation of them is 14 with my brain. But! I need a command to output `14' automatically.

And now the expl3-foo-sum is: \foosum{}

\end{document}


Here's a version, using the decrement and add features of expl3:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{;/,}\ignoreemptyitems

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \readlist*\foo{
        foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5;
        3,1,4,1,5
    }
    
    \newcommand\foosum[0]{
        % ~~~ initialization ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \int_new:N  \l_int_mine_cnt
        \int_set:Nn \l_int_mine_cnt { \listlen\foo[2] }
        
        \int_new:N  \l_int_mine_sum
        \int_set:Nn \l_int_mine_sum { 0 }
        
        % ~~~ loop, i.e. sum it up ~~~~~~~~~
        \int_while_do:nn { \l_int_mine_cnt > 0 } {
            % ~~~ sum up ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \int_add:Nn \l_int_mine_sum { \foo[2,\l_int_mine_cnt] }
            % ~~~ end-condition ~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \int_decr:N \l_int_mine_cnt
        }
        
        % ~~~ "return" sum, i.e. put it into the output stream ~~~
        \int_use:N \l_int_mine_sum
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff



% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

Elements in the second line of the group are: \foo[2], and there are \listlen\foo[2] elements in the second line of the group.

I can figure out the summation of them is 14 with my brain. But! I need a command to output `14' automatically.

And now the expl3-foo-sum is: \foosum{}

\end{document}

